# Why does ozone have such a large solubility in water?

Tags: water, solubility, ozone

At $25~\mathrm{^\circ C}$, the solubility of ozone is $109~\mathrm{mg~L^{-1}}$. This is $13$ times higher than the solubility of diatomic oxygen. What causes this?

Comment: It is polar. That would be my guess.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at the molecular structure of ozone below, you can see that it is polar.  Diatomic oxygen is non-polar.  This mild polarity of ozone greatly enhances the solubility of the molecule in a polar solvent like water.

[image]